# save a pandas groupby object into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue that I cannot figure out although I read similar posts such as [Pandas groupby to to_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602097/pandas-groupby-to-to-csv). It does not work for me. I am trying to write code to separate each group from a groupby object and save each group into its own excel spreadsheet.

I attached a toy example of the code that I did to get my groupby object on pandas with some columns.

Now, I need to save each group from this object into a separate csv file, or at least in a separate worksheet in excel.

```
dff = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': ['001', '002', '003'],
                    'revenue_contribution_in_percentage': [0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
                    'BuyPrice' : [2,3,4],
                    'SellPrice' : [5,6,6],
                    'margin' : [3,3,2],
                    'Avg_per_week' : [3,2,5],
                    'StockOnHand' : [4,10,20],
                            'StockOnOrder': [0,0,0],
                            'Supplier' : ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABZ' ],
                            'SupplierLeadTime': [5,5,5],
                            'cumul_value':[0.4,0.6,1],
                            'class_mention':['A','A','B'],
                            'std_week':[1,2,1],
                            'review_time' : [2,2,2],
                            'holding_cost': [0.35, 0.35, 0.35],
                            'aggregate_order_placement_cost': [200, 230,210]
})
```

I have done the following to get a groupby supplier object

```
groups = [group.reset_index().set_index(['SKU'])[[
                            'revenue_contribution_in_percentage',
                            'BuyPrice',
                            'SellPrice',
                            'margin',
                            'Avg_per_week',
                            'StockOnHand',
                            'StockOnOrder',
                            'Supplier',
                            'SupplierLeadTime',
                            'cumul_value',
                            'class_mention',
                            'std_week',
                            'review_time',
                            'holding_cost',
                            'aggregate_order_placement_cost',
                            'periods']] for _, group in dff.groupby('Supplier')]

df_group = pd.DataFrame(groups).sum()
group_to_excel = df_group.to_csv('results.csv')
```

and the output that I would like to get is the folowing: two distinct datasets that can saved in csv format and look like this:

```
   SKU  revenue_contribution_in_percentage  BuyPrice  SellPrice  margin  \
0  001                                 0.2         2          5       3   
1  002                                 0.5         3          6       3   

   Avg_per_week  StockOnHand  StockOnOrder Supplier  SupplierLeadTime  \
0             3            4             0      ABC                 5   
1             2           10             0      ABC                 5   

   cumul_value class_mention  std_week  review_time  holding_cost  \
0          0.4             A         1            2          0.35   
1          0.6             A         2            2          0.35   

   aggregate_order_placement_cost  
0                             200  
1                             230
```

and

```
   SKU  revenue_contribution_in_percentage  BuyPrice  SellPrice  margin  \
0  003                                 0.3         4          6       2   

   Avg_per_week  StockOnHand  StockOnOrder Supplier  SupplierLeadTime  \
0             5           20             0      ABZ                 5   

   cumul_value class_mention  std_week  review_time  holding_cost  \
0            1             B         1            2          0.35   

   aggregate_order_placement_cost  
0                             210
```

At this point my code give one and only worksheet (horrendous worksheet) with pretty much nothing on it. I am not sure what is wrong at this point. 
I would greatly appreciate some help on this one! thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you specify what you want in the spreadsheet? Ideally with some dummy data so it is possible to reproduce? We do not know what the variable group contains.

Comment: where is df2? i'm getting an error on `groups`

Comment: sorry for the typo, df2 is actually dff, I just updated my code.

Comment: This answer can help with the accessing groups by keys: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734533/how-to-access-pandas-groupby-dataframe-by-key

Access each group on loop and save them individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `groupby` as you are not aggregating anything. What you really want is to slice `dff` by each unique supplier and export them to their own files. Try this:

```
cols = [
    'SKU',
    'revenue_contribution_in_percentage',
    'BuyPrice',
    'SellPrice',
    'margin',
    'Avg_per_week',
    'StockOnHand',
    'StockOnOrder',
    'Supplier',
    'SupplierLeadTime',
    'cumul_value',
    'class_mention',
    'std_week',
    'review_time',
    'holding_cost',
    'aggregate_order_placement_cost'
]

for supplier in dff['Supplier'].unique():
    sub_dff = dff[dff['Supplier'] == supplier][cols]
    sub_dff.to_csv(f'{supplier}_data.csv')
```