# Sum up / group by and export to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, export-to-csv

Suppose I have the following dataframe called "df":

```
ID;Type
1;A
1;A
1;A
1;A
1;A
2;A
2;A
3;B
4;A
4;B
```

Now I want to sum up / group by this dataframe by ID and Type and export the result as a csv.

The result should look like:

```
ID;Type;Count
1;A;5
2;A;2
3;B;1
4;A;1
4;B;1
```

My code for summing up / group by is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
frameexport=df.groupby(["ID", "Type"])["Type"].count()
print(frameexport)

ID  Type
1   A       5
2   A       2
3   B       1
4   A       1
    B       1
```

This is not exaclty what I hoped for. The last entry for ID 4 is not repeating the "4" again.

I try to export it to a csv:

```
frameexport.to_csv(r'C:\Path\file.csv', index=False, sep=";")
```

But it doesn't work, it just looks like this:

```
Type
5
2
1
1
1
```

Problem here is that [I call it on an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602097/pandas-groupby-to-to-csv) and obviously to_csv doesn't work like this.

How can I get the desired result:

```
ID  Type    Count
1   A       5
2   A       2
3   B       1
4   A       1
4   B       1
```

exported to a csv?

Comment: `df.groupby(["ID", "Type"])["Type"].count().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

There is `MultiIndex Serie`, so need remove `index=False` and for correct column name is used `rename`:

```
frameexport.rename('Count').to_csv(r'C:\Path\file.csv', sep=";")
```

Or create DataFrame by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), then default index is necessary omit, so `index=False` is correct:

```
frameexport.reset_index(name='Count').to_csv(r'C:\Path\file.csv', index=False, sep=";")
```